# Keep getting error when trying to use '\copy' in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Here is the query I've been trying to run:

```
create or replace function save_to_csv(mesa text)
returns void as $$
begin 
    execute '\copy (select distinct aid::text,
                                    rid::text, 
                                    did::text 
                    from ' || mesa || 
                  ') 
             to ''/home/datascientist/Data/User_Journey_Map/updated_data/all_ids/'|| mesa ||'_ids.csv''';
end;
$$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

I keep getting this error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
> Where: PL/pgSQL function save_to_csv(text) line 3 at EXECUTE
> SQL statement "SELECT save_to_csv(mesa)"
> PL/pgSQL function save_tables() line 21 at PERFORM

However, if I delete the ' \' before 'copy' I get this error:

> SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open file "/home/datascientist/Data/User Journey Map/updated_data/all_ids/tca__clicked_ids.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
> Hint: COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
> Where: SQL statement "copy (select distinct aid::text, rid::text, did::text from tca__clicked) to '/home/datascientist/Data/User Journey Map/updated_data/all_ids/tca__clicked_ids.csv'"
> PL/pgSQL function save_to_csv(text) line 3 at EXECUTE
> SQL statement "SELECT save_to_csv(mesa)"
> PL/pgSQL function save_tables() line 21 at PERFORM

I've tried implementing the solutions given at:
[PostgreSQL syntax error when using EXECUTE in Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861374/postgresql-syntax-error-when-using-execute-in-function)
and
[I am trying to copy a file, but getting error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031813/i-am-trying-to-copy-a-file-but-getting-error-message) , but neither have helped and I can't find anything else that looks helpful.

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` command and not available in (the Postgres dialect of) SQL (nor PL/pgSQL). `COPY` on the other hand is. But files for `COPY` are local to the *server*. `/home/datascientist/Data/User Journey Map/updated_data/all_ids/` likely doesn't exist on the machine where the server is running.

Comment: Ooohhhhhhhh thanks that makes a lot of sense.