# Syntac Error when using EXECUTE command in postgresql Function

Tags: postgresql, function, execute

I'm trying to write a function which executes a dynamically prepared sql query and return the result as table.

I was refering to the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861374/postgresql-syntax-error-when-using-execute-in-function), it mentioned to use `language plpgsql`, even after using it I'm getting the same syntax error.

Below is the function code provided.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.execute_test(
    ddsmappingids text,
    totalnumberofrecords bigint,
    skiprecords bigint,
    pagesize integer,
    cid bigint)
    RETURNS TABLE(sampletime timestamp without time zone, jsonstring text, rowscount bigint) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
table_names text:='dynamictable';
sql_query text;
dsids_array int[];
sub_query text;
BEGIN
    if cid>=2 then
      select 'dynamictable_'||cid into table_names;
    end if;
    select string_to_array(ddsmappingids, ',')::int[] into dsids_array;
    sub_query:='SELECT * , COUNT(*) over() AS row_count FROM (SELECT start_time, cast(jsonb_object_agg(vw.dataseries_name, ROUND(CAST(o.dbl_value as numeric), 4)) as text) AS DataSeriesValue 
FROM ' || quote_ident(table_names) ||' o
join vwdds vw on o.ddmid=vw.id    
where ddmid in (' || array_to_string(dsids_array,',') || ')
and o.dbl_value is not null
GROUP BY start_time
ORDER BY start_time desc
limit ' || totalnumberofrecords || ') t offset '|| skiprecords || ' rows fetch next ' || pagesize || ' rows only;';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Temporary table created';
    RETURN QUERY Execute sub_query;
END
$BODY$;
```

Error Message when running the function
[image]

`EXECUTE` command, when i try with some simple query it is working fine, but the query mentioned in the code snippet it is giving syntax error.
Please help me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried that exact query outside of the function?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, the exact query is running and its giving results also